# Totaling a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a SQL Query in phpmyadmin that will total multiple rows and insert that total into the cell.

The file is sorted by date and then a few other specifics.

I am just having a hard time finding the syntax for it.

Basically I have one column called 'Points' and another called 'Total_Points'

It needs to look like this:

```
+--------+--------------+
| Points | Total Points |
+--------+--------------+
|   10   |      10      |
|   10   |      20      |
|   10   |      30      |
|   10   |      40      |
+--------+--------------+
```

And so on and so on.
It seems like there has to be something out there that would do this and I am just missing it

Comment: So do you want the "Total Points" to be a running total?

Comment: You need to specify the database.  Some databases such as Oracle and Teradata easily support running sums.  In other databases, it is more complicated.

Comment: Try searching for [`[mysql] running total`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+running+total) (although your problem seems more complicated, because you want to update the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a running sum you can use "window functions" like this:

```
create table tbl(ord int, points int);
insert into tbl values(1, 10),(2, 10), (3, 10), (4, 10);

select
    *,
    sum(points) over w total_points
from tbl
window w as (order by ord);

 ord | points | total_points 
-----+--------+--------------
   1 |     10 |           10
   2 |     10 |           20
   3 |     10 |           30
   4 |     10 |           40
```

I "aggregated" your `ORDER BY` criteria to be the column `ord`. You may of course replace it.

Besides of this: You did not specify a concrete database vendor. My example runs on PostgreSQL. Other SQL dialects may be a little different.

Comment: MySQL (which turned to be the one that Chris is using) is one of the few DBMS to not support this standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of discussion about cumulative sums in SQL.

You may want to look at [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/07/28/SQL-Server-2005-Fast-Running-Totals.aspx). If speed isn't a big issue, you can also simply use:

```
select t1.id, t1.SomeNumt, SUM(t2.SomeNumt) as sum 
from @t t1 
inner join @t t2 
  on t1.id >= t2.id 
  group by t1.id, t1.SomeNumt 
  order by t1.id
```

The key issue is that SQL doesn't actually store rows in any order. The ieda of a 'running total' assumes that the rows have an order, and by default, this isn't true. In SQL Server 2012, there is a function for this, but until people are using it, this is the best we can do.

Comment: Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2 and Teradata had the ability to do running totals for a long time (See. A.H. answer). SQL Server has finally caught up in that area.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.  It is MySql. And I am looking for a running total.    So before I can total them I need to sort them in the correct order (date) and then total them.   That helps.  Getting closer I think